# Calculate the commutator subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups

So I have been tasked with calculating the commutator subgroup of $S_4$. As a warmup, I was able to calculate the commutator subgroup of $S_3$ through brute force calculations as there were only $6^2$ possibilities. I found that ${S_3}^{'}=\{e,(1\,\,2\,\,3),\,(1\,\,3\,\,2)\}$.

For $S_4$, I clearly do not want to attempt all $24^2$ computations, so what kind of strategy could I employ to get this done in a reasonable amount of time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First note that all commutators will be even permutations.

Then note that $[(a,c),(b,c)] = (a, b, c)$, if $a, b, c$ are distinct.

So in $S_{4}'$ you find all the $3$-cycles.

Comment: 1.) All commutators are even permutations: Right. I saw that in the case for $S_3$ as well now that I look over my work in light of this comment. 

2.) In $S_4^{'}$ contains all the 3-cycles: Since each 3-cycle can be decomposed into two 2-cycles (since they are even permutations), I should also find all the two 2-cycles which do not give rise to 3-cycles as well and the identity. Thus $|S_4^{'}|=12$ and $S_4^{'}=A_4$. 

Of course I have to provide details, but this gets me there.

Comment: It might help to add a line or two why all commutators are even permutations.

Answer (score 5):

First, observe that each basic commutator $\;[a,b]\;,\;\;a,b\in S_4\;$ is in fact in $\;A_4\;$ . This can also be seen as follows :

$\;S_4/A_4\cong C_2\;$ is abelian and thus $\;[S_4,S_4]\le A_4\;$.

Now just count up some elements and deduce $\;S_4'=A_4\;$ , for example taking into account that $\;A_4\;$ has no subgroup of order six.

Comment: Is this enough to rule out the possibility that $|S_4'| = 4$?

Comment: @Junglemath After you do some counting, yes: it is. For example, $\;S_4'\;$ contains all $\;3\,-$ cycles, and thus it can't be $\;|S_4'|=4\;$ by Lagrange's Theorem...